# More effective way to implement big amount of events

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to Visual C#, I am implementing a WPF application but I want to use a more effective way for events since I have another method for every single tool.

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    KeyUp(textBox1, e);
}
private void textBox2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    KeyUp(textBox2, e);
}
private void textBox3_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    KeyUp(textBox3, e);
}
private void textBox4_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    KeyUp(textBox4, e);
}
private void textBox5_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    KeyUp(textBox5, e);
}
private void TextChanged(int x, TextBox txt)
{
    int i = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[x].Value = txt.Text;
}
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextChanged(1, textBox2);
}
private void textBox3_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextChanged(2, textBox3);
}
private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextChanged(3, textBox4);
}
private void textBox5_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextChanged(4, textBox5);
}
```

and so on. Instead of occupying so much lines, I am looking for a shorter way for all these events. Seems like I have to use Mapping, but I could not manage it. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: The _sender_ parameter is the TextBox that originated the event

Answer (score 1):

You could use one event handler for all textbox keyup events as follows;

```
private void textBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    KeyUp((TextBox)sender, e);           
}
```

you could use same kind of logic for rest of the events once you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need two event handlers (they are reusable you know)

First:

```
private void OnTextBoxKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    KeyUp((Textbox)sender, e);
}
```

Second:

```
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (Textbox)sender;

    var i = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    var x = (int)textbox.Tag

    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[x].Value = textBox.Text;
}
```

For the second part you need to set the `FrameworkElement.Tag` property in code like so:

```
<Textbox Tag="1" />
```

For completeness sake here is the xaml part for your textboxes:

```
<Textbox x:Name="textBox1" Tag="1" TextChanged="OnTextChanged" KeyUp="OnTextBoxKeyUp"/>
<Textbox x:Name="textBox2" Tag="2" TextChanged="OnTextChanged" KeyUp="OnTextBoxKeyUp"/>
```

And so on. Note that `x:Name` part is probably not needed as you don't need to reference the textboxes by name in the code behind with this solution.

Comment: Awesome :) plus one from me!

Answer (score 0):

First give your textboxes name as
TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3 ... and add a common `textBoxAll_TextChanged` event handler for all textboxes.

Then execute the below code :

```
private void textBoxAll_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    int x = int.Parse(tb.Name.Substring(7,1)) - 1;
    TextChanged(x, tb);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not reduce the amount of code lines which is my main purpose.

Comment: Thank you this is absolutely more effective than what I did. However, I am looking for a way that I will not need to add something under all textbox events. I want to avoid any repeating. I need event mapping , but cannot manage how to do it .

Comment: This is the best way to handle your issue.

Comment: this idea of detecting the column number as int  without passing an extra parameter helped me a lot.Thanks!!